# Polling GPS position via wap page

Tags: gps, wap

I'm in the middle of writing a project that is web driven, and part of the application will be a data logging exercise carried out by our team of guards. What I need to know is : Is there any way to write the WAP page to poll the phone's GPS system for a location, and pass that up in to one of the database fields? I don't mind if we have to stick to a particular brand of phone, i.e. Nokia.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to take a look at: [Silver GPS](http://blogs.msdn.com/jbarnes/archive/2008/12/02/silver-gps-complete-demo-code-and-updated-silverlight-project.aspx)

Abstract:

How to create an end-to-end Mobile GPS tracking application using the .NET Compact Framework, WCF, LINQ, Silverlight, Deep Zoom, and Virtual Earth.

Inspired by a true-story mobility case study recently published on the Microsoft.com website, this session will walk you through how to create a mobile GPS tracking application using the .NET Compact Framework, Windows Mobile SDK, and Compact SQL.

At the Web host layer, we will create a Windows Communication Foundation service and generate a Compact framework client proxy to send the GPS tracks to a host web server - where finally, the GPS trail can then be viewed using LINQ, Silverlight, Deep Zoom, and Virtual Earth.

Includes all source code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

You could write a tiny J2ME application that transmits the coordinates over HTTP; most modern phones that support GPS also support [JSR179 Location API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=179) that makes it quite simple.